# Mean and variance of random variable

Tags: statistics

I have a random variable x with a mean of 4 and standard deviation of 2 and want to find the mean and variance of 9x.

Sorry if this seems like a really basic question but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may want to start with writing down the things in the correct form. For example mean $E[X]=4$ how do you write the standard deviation? and how do you write down the variance of $9X$? how they are linked?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ denote mean and variance of random variable $X$ then:

- $\mathbb E(aX+b)=a\mu+b$
- $\operatorname{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\sigma^2$